# 2D matrix, find all the numbers on a straight path between two numbers

Tags: algorithm

If given a square 2D matrix of arbitrary size, how to find all the numbers on a path in between two selected numbers. e.g:

```
    |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |
    |----+----+----+----|
    |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
    |----+----+----+----|
    |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
    |----+----+----+----|
    | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
```

- for 6,16 = {11}
- for 3,15 = {7,11}
- for 9,2 = {}
- for 4,13 = {7,10}
- for 8,10 = {}
- for 12,9 = {11,10}
- etc.

Comment: Are the numbers necessarily 1, 2, 3, ... ? If so, a `map` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's build a function to find the position for any number in the `n x n` matrix:

```
position(a) = ((a - 1) / n, (a - 1) % n)
```

Then, given 2 numbers `a` and `b`, take `position(a) = (ax, ay)` and `position(b) = (bx, by)`.

- If they are in the same line, `ax - bx = 0`.
- If they are in the same column, `ay - by = 0`.
- If they are in diagonal of each other, `abs(ax - bx) = abs(ay - by)`.

Just evaluate the conditions and print the elements in the correct order:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int m[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};

int main(){
    int n = 4;
    while(true){
        int a, b;
        cin>>a>>b;                     //input elements
        int ax = (a - 1) % n, ay = (a - 1) / n;
        int bx = (b - 1) % n, by = (b - 1) / n;
        pair<int, int> p;

        int dx = bx - ax;
        int dy = by - ay;

        if(dx == 0 || dy == 0 || abs(dx) == abs(dy)) 
            p = make_pair(dx < 0? -1 : dx > 0, dy < 0? -1 : dy > 0);
        else continue;  //there isnt a path in this case

        while(true){
            ax += p.first; ay += p.second;
            if(ax != bx || ay != by) cout<<m[ay][ax]<<endl;
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Complexity: **O(n)**, since at most **n** elements can be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Work in X/Y coordinates *(they might be calculated from values using integer division and moudulo, if needed*)

Calculate [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (Greatest common divisor) of differences by horizontal and by vertical.

```
int gcd (int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return gcd (b, a % b);
}

dx = abs(x2 - x1);
dy = abs(y2 - y1);
gc = gcd(dx, dy);
```

Number of inner integer points is `n = gc-1`, so you can make simple loop

```
xstep = (x2 - x1) / gc;
ystep = (y2 - y1) / gc;  //both are integer values
for (i = 1; i < gc; i++) {
   x = x1 + xstep * i;
   y = y1 + ystep * i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I've made the simplifying assumption that you only want to step to immediately adjacent cells. In this case you're only looking at horizontal, vertical or diagonal (45 degree) paths. However, as the grid gets bigger it is possible to consider straight-line paths through cell centers that skip over adjacent cells. For example, 10 and 19 lie between 1 and 28 on a size 7 grid - the example provided by **MBo** in his comment. To handle these cases you'll need to incorporate the Greatest Common Divisor in determining the step size, as **MBo** has outlined in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61401376/6438819).

Just calculate the row and column difference in the positions and step from the first cell to the second.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static int[] gridCells(int size, int from, int to)
{
    int fromRow = (from-1) / size;
    int fromCol = (from-1) % size;

    int toRow = (to-1) / size;
    int toCol = (to-1) % size;

    int rowDiff = toRow - fromRow;
    int colDiff = toCol - fromCol;

    if(rowDiff == 0 || colDiff == 0 || Math.abs(rowDiff) == Math.abs(colDiff))
    {
        int maxStep = Math.max(Math.abs(rowDiff), Math.abs(colDiff));           
        if(maxStep > 1)
        {
            int rowStep = rowDiff / maxStep;
            int colStep = colDiff / maxStep;
            int[] cells = new int[maxStep-1];
            for(int i=0; i<cells.length; i++)           
                cells[i] = (fromRow + (i+1)*rowStep) * size + fromCol + ((i+1)*colStep) + 1;
            return cells;
        }
    }

    return new int[]{};
}
```

Test:

```
for(int[] t : new int[][] {{5,5}, {6,16}, {3,15}, {9,2}, {4,13}, {8,10}, {12,9}})
    System.out.format("%s : %s%n", Arrays.toString(t), Arrays.toString(gridCells(4, t[0], t[1])));
```

Output:

```
[5, 5] : []
[6, 16] : [11]
[3, 15] : [7, 11]
[9, 2] : []
[4, 13] : [7, 10]
[8, 10] : []
[12, 9] : [11, 10]
```

Comment: Sadly, gives correct results only for horizontal, vertical and 45 degrees paths [ideone](https://ideone.com/qDaJGr)  (expected {18}  and {10, 19} for the last pairs)